# Computing values of the Lilliefors c.d.f

Tags: distributions, computational-statistics, numerical-integration

How up-to-date is the assertion in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilliefors_test) that tables of the Lilliefors distribution have been computed only by Monte Carlo methods?

(It would seem preferable to use deterministic numerical methods if possible.)